# fetch api or xmlhttprequest compatibility and browser support

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I am learning ajax programming techniques . But I have found that xmlhttprequest is deprecated and now I have to use fetch api . But according to MDN the fetch api is experimental . That means its behavior may change in future .

[Compatibility of the browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#browser_compatibility)

So can any one give me a solution that will be future proof and also browser compatible.

Comment: @Seblor — As far as I know, Babel has no features relating to XHR or fetch.

Comment: But I want to know how it works

Comment: @Quentin ah my bad, I thought it had a polyfill for fetch.

Comment: Microsoft themself have dropped support and ditch IE11 and legancy edge in office365. It's down at 0.7% marketshare world wide. Just ditch IE entierly and you will feel happy as a developer. And we will solute you for making everyone else having to upgrade there browser - pick fetch!

Answer (score 1):

> I have found that xmlhttprequest is deprecated

The [specification](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/) does not mark it as deprecated.

> But according to MDN the fetch api is experimental

The only thing the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) has to say about fetch being experimental is:

> Browsers have started to add experimental support for the AbortController and AbortSignal interfaces (aka The Abort API),

Fetch, as a whole, is *not* experimental.

> So can any one give me a solution that will be future proof and also browser compatible.

Pick either (or a library that wraps one of them) based on the features that you need.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/12/chrome-80-deps-rems#disallow_synchronous_xmlhttprequest_in_page_dismissal

Comment: I put a link where it is said that xmlhttprequest will be removed .

Comment: @Hasnathabdullahaknd — That isn't what that link says. **synchronous calls** to XHR have been deprecated forever (because they block which is awful) and that just removes them entirely in some very narrow circumstances. Standard asynchronous calls are untouched.

Comment: so then I can use all the asynchronous functionalities using xmlhttprequest ???

Comment: Just use `fetch` and not `XMLHttpRequest`.

`fetch` is supported by modern browsers and easier to use than `XMLHttpRequest`.  `fetch` doesn't work in Internet Explorer (IE) at all. But it's not recommended to support IE as it's a security risk anyway.